# Serving single HTTP request with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, websphere

Angular 4 application sends a list of records to a Java spring MVC application that has been deployed in Websphere 8 Servlet container. The list is then inserted into to a temp table. After the batch insert, a procedure call is made in order to do some calculations and return  results. Depending on the size of the list that was inserted into temp table it may take anywhere between: 3000ms( N ~ 500 ), 6000ms( N ~ 1000 ), 50,000+ms ( N > 2000 ).

My asendach would be to create chunks of data and  simultaneously send them to database for processing. After threads (Futures) return results I would aggregate them and return back to the client. To sum up, I would split a synchronous call into multiple asynchronous processes(simultaneously executed) and return back to the client over the same thread that initiated HTTP call - landed into my controller.

Everything would be fine and I would not be asking this questions if a more experienced colleague of mine was not strongly disagreeing with this approach. His reasoning is that using this approach is prone to exceptions due to thread interrupts / timeouts / semaphores and so on. Hi is going as far as saying that multithreading should be avoided within a web container because it can crash the Servlet container in case it runs out of threads. 
He proposes that we should have the browser send multiple AJAX requests and aggregates/present data in chunks.

Can you please help me understand which approach is better and why?

Comment: Sounds simpler to send parallel requests then to write a bunch of server-side code, but not because there's any inherent issue with offloading work from a servlet onto multiple threads.

Comment: In that case client has to deal with not only presenting the data but aggregating as well.Wouldn't that add more overhead on the client side?.
I already wrote the server side code (untested the heck out of it) but am ready to ditch it if that is not the way to do it...

Comment: I don't think either approach is objectively right or wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your approach is much better.

1. Threads created by application logic aren't application container threads and limited only by operating system. While each AJAX request uses a thread from application container. So the second approach reduces throughput and increases the possibility of reaching application container limit while and the first one not. Performance also should be considered because it's much cheaper to create a thread than to send a request over network. Plus each network requests uses additional resources for authentication/authorization/encryption etc.
2. It's definetely harder to write correct multithread code and it can easily prone to errors. However it shouldn't stop you from doing it because concurrency can significantly increase your performance. It's pretty straightforward to handle interrupts and timeouts using Future and you for sure don't need semaphores here.
3. Exposing this logic to client looks like breaking of encapsulation. Imagine that you use rest api which forces you to send multiple request by splitting you data in chunks. What chunk size should i use? How to deal with timeouts/interrupts? How many requests should i sent? etc. You will have almost the same challenges in both approaches, but it's much easier to deal with them using specially designed for this libraries like ExecutorService and Future.